# Simplifying the declaration of a dictionary where the value of a key is the property name as a string

Tags: typescript

I have the following constant:

```
const X = {
  x: 'x',
  y: 'y',
  z: 'z'
}
```

Is there a way to write this without repetitions?

P.S: Found something like this in production code but way longer, don't know what the point is.

Comment: Do you want to add infinite dynamic key values or numerable key values?

Comment: Honestly if it were up to me I'd just delete this altogether. I guess I'm just wondering to what extent I can simplify expressions to end up with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just a function that tales keys as parameters and returns an object?

```
const getDictionnary = (keys: string[]): {[key: string]: string} => {
    return keys.reduce(
        (object: {[key: string]: string}, currentKey: string) => ({...object, [currentKey]: currentKey})
        , {});
}
```